# Cube root modulo prime

Tags: finite-field

I make research about big numbers in finite fields and I need to calculate a cube root modulo prime `P` for the number `N`:

`N = 33307028807218380701173040920772273133747152666242396962200448019852017733098`.

`P = 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663`

All algorithms that I can find over the web is not for modulo prime, or can not calculate cube roots of this number `N`.

Please, can anyone share the algorithm for finding the cube roots for this number in finite field of `P`.

Comment: Hint: the little Fermat theorem tells that since $P$ is prime, if $X\not\equiv0\pmod P$ then $X^{P-1}\equiv1\pmod P$. That holds for example for $X=N$, and for the number $X$ such that $X^3\equiv N\pmod P$ that you want to compute.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

There is no cubic root for this N in GF(P).

But if, for example, N=1, you would run [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) (or  [on your computer](https://www.sagemath.org/download.html)):

```
GF(115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663)(1).nth_root(3, all=True)
```

That will return a list of 3 elements, that are all cubic roots of 1 in Fp.

Comment: Technically you can link a permalink that contains your code. Example [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVyrEKwlAMBdBfcXwPpCQvyc3N4Ko_4C4OQofSQmn_Xx3Odh73phpZQ1jD0hRa4cMipRgiBLMkGTZQRQcCLn9WHhl0kV8gzZEKWG_ap_WYX_u2Hc2ul_ey3J77-elf0WMY-g==&lang=sage&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==)